# http upload error as a subscribed user

Tags: uploads, errors, nginx, http

Im getting an http error when uploading a featured image as a Subscriber. If I upgrade the user to editor or admin all works well. My server is Ubuntu 12.10, NGINX, WP 3.5.1

I have checked php.ini already, no success.

Comment: Exactly what error do you get? Please post the exact message.

Answer (score 0):

The Subscriber user role does not have write permissions.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Subscriber

Perhaps you should give the user the Contributor role.

> **Contributor** 
>   delete_posts
>   edit_posts
>   read

http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor

Answer (score 0):

The codex contains a nice diagram regarding [Roles & Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). As you can see the Subscriber role has only one capability: `read`.

The first role that has the capability `upload_files` is the author role.

That is the reason why in a default/blank wordpress install a subscriber is not able to upload any files.

If you haven't changed anything (via plugins or PHP coding) a subscriber shouldn't even be able to create any post/pages, so he shouldn't be able to even get to any place where he could possibly upload an featured image.

As you didn't mention what you are trying to achieve there are two possible ways now; update the role of that user to (atleast) author or grant the subsriber role the capability to upload files via [add_cap()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im using Events Manager Pro which allows subscribed users to manage via the WP back-end. I  would like subscribed users to add events + featured images. I'll try modifying the default signup role as a contributor to see if that works. Although I really dont want them to post blogs just manage there event listings.

Comment: update.. contributor is also reporting an http upload error

Comment: As said in the post above: the first role that has the capability `upload_files` is the author role. 

But you could also easily add an own role for this purpose and only assign the capabilities that are really needed. Just have a look at: [add_role()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) I would prefer this over giving unknown users the author status.